# ST201 Ethernet driver for linux

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, debian

I found an old Dell Optiplex GX620 and plan on using it as a router for a network for our student club. There is one ethernet controller onboard on the motherboard, and a friend had an older PCI ethernet card laying around (it says PPT PM45 1030M on the hardware).

The issue is that I don't think there's a driver present in my kernel for the PCI card. I've done some googling, but didn't find much relevant. Some outputs:

```
$ lspci -nnk
Ethernet controller [0200]: Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp ST201 Sundance Ethernet [13f0:0201] (rev 14)
Subsystem: D-Link Systen Inc Device [1186:1002]
```

For all other entries it mentions 'Kernel driver in use:', but not for this one...

```
$ lspci -vmmnn
Slot:     04:00.0
Class:    Ethernet controller [0200]
Vendor    Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp [13f0]
SVendor:  D-Link System Inc [1186]
SDevice:  Device [1002]
Rev:      14
```

I found that using the sundance driver should work, but:

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep sundance
Module      Size    Used By
sundance    22363   0
mii         12675   1 sundance
```

I'm not really sure what to do next, if I can't resolve this within a week I guess i'll just go buy a cheap out-of-the-box supported PCI card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel needs to be compiled with `CONFIG_SUNDANCE` in order to support the *Alta* chip. The resulting module will be called `sundance`.

http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SUNDANCE.html

Comment: Looking in the configuration file /boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64 (I'm assuming this is the config file used to compile the kernel in use at the moment?), grepping "SUNDANCE" returns 'CONFIG_SUNDANCE=m'. Does this mean it is compiled as a module, and I can load it? Or should I just compile with 'CONFIG_SUNDANCE=y'? I haven't really compiled a kernel before, so I'm not sure how it works a 100%.

Comment: CONFIG_SUNDANCE=m means that there's already a module. Try to load it with _modprobe sundance_. If successful, load it on startup (/etc/modules).

Comment: Okay, adding the module to the kernel seems to have worked (ifconfig -a shows eth1 now at least), although I let the kernel compile while I was doing other things. Still learnt a lot by doing so, thanks a ton!